# Communication between two WCF service libraries on the same Windows Service host

Tags: wcf, appdomain

The project I'm currently working on includes a server that receives C# scripts (partial code) from clients, wraps it to create a complete class, compiles it then load it into a separate AppDomain for execution.

A task (currently running script) can send feedback to the user at any point of it's execution, as defined in the script by the user. And possibly the task might wait for a response from the user (currently assuming it's only right after having sent feedback). And the user might, at any moment, decide to kill a task.

The server is implemented as a Windows Service hosting a WCF Service Library.

As I don't want to overcomplicate the client to make it communicate directly with the dynamically created AppDomains, the (partial) solution that I considered after some research was hosting a second WCF service with named pipe binding to make the dynamic AppDomains use it as a relay between them and the client facing WCF service.

My issue is that now I can't think of a clean way to have the two WCF services interact.

My ideas are:

1. Having them maintain direct references to each other:
   Seeing as Normally both of the services are singletons it shouldn't be hard to do.
   But that would be a pain to maintain in the case one of them fails and needs to be restarted. (I'm still new to WCF so I have no idea how common that is, but it's still an issue to consider. I think.)
2. Introducing some sort of a "message queue" (or two, one for each direction) with properties that can be set and subscribed to. Thus when one service sets a property an event will be triggered in the second. But that feels somewhat hacky to me, even though I can't really think of any clear issues.

I could really use some expert input on what I'm trying to accomplish, be it opinions on my thoughts or new ideas. Even if that involves rethinking the architecture. This project is still in an early enough stage to afford some rework, as long as there is enough reason to do that of course.

Since I've put lots of efforts (read: 2 minutes on paint) to prepare a quick (read: useless) schema of the system, I'll link it here since I don't have the reputation to post images:
[Link to schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ohWD.png)

---

**Edit:**

As I now have the reputation thanks to an upvote:
[image: Basic structure]

Still after rereading my question, I feel that perhaps I have been looking at this issue from a too narrow perspective by thinking of the services as something more special than ordinary classes. The more I think about it the more I feel that the observer pattern is probably the best approach to take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record, and to avoid leaving my (silly) question unanswered, I've realised that I was looking at this too narrowly by trying to find a solution specific to WCF services.
And finally I ended up using a variation of the observer pattern (based on the [`IObservable<T>`Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Comment: Actually your question wasnt silly at all. One of my running projects is about the same architecture, using 2.0 remoting to cross the inner appdomaon boundary. I am in the process of replacing that with wcf services.

Comment: Furthermore it makes alot of sense to run the "script" inside its own appdomaon boundary - this is a sound insulation and gives you the ability to scrap the whole domain on demand f.ex

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. The way I handled a duplex communication between the two servers is as following:

For each process (AppDomain Seperated Task) create a pair of WCF services. Both services have their Instancing set to PerSession (no need for singleton which may cause problems in the long run like disconnect). This means the Client will be communicating for each process (AppDomain Separated Task) with two distinct Service instances or a service pair (i.e. Service1 and Service2). 
We want a duplex communication in between these two services, which means that both can communicate with the other and pass data (in the form of a DataContract class object).

For this:
    1- Declare two services (i.e. in a separate class library) and host them (self hosting or else).

    2- Create your DataContract class and add any property, collection, enum etc. as you like. Both services must have a get-set property for this class.

    3- In the same class library (where the Service1 and 2 classes reside), create another class. This class will act as a depository for the Service pair instances. It has a static List in order to register the service pair instances (you can identify each service with a GUID).

    4- We setup the client proxy using svcUtil.exe (or by code). When the client makes a service request, a service (i.e. service1) will be created by the WCF. At service1, create or launch the process (App Domain Separated Task) as client2 and at its constructor create the Service2 proxy by code. 

    5- Initialize the Service2 instance (i.e. by a call to the service2) and register the service pair instances at static list of the depository (so that it can be retrieved later for duplex communication). Now we have both service instances and both of them are registered as a pair into a static list.

    6- Start communication between both services by making a call from Client1 proxy.

    7- At Service1 call method, retrieve the service pair from the static list. Deep copy (DeepClone) the Datacontract class object from Service1 to the Service2 using the get-set property mentioned at (2). (Note that you can use one of the many Deep Clone libraries from Nuget like DeepCloner).

    8- Make a call back from Service2. Client2 now has the identical DataContract class property values as Client1 

    9- Repeat steps 6-8 for Client2 proxy for Service2-Service1 communication.